# Reversing the subtract algorithm (Jailbreak App Flex 3)

Tags: flex3, jailbreak

I recently started using flex 3 to patch games and get more aware of coding and what certain things do.

I made a patch for this app called Highrise and was successful in getting it to operate by giving the user +3,000 bubbles when their profile is liked instead of the programmed +2 bubbles.

The only problem now is that it gives the user the amount but it disappears once you leave the room or close the app and it doesn't process when going to purchase something in the games store.

I received one suggestion so far which was to try "Reversing the subtract algorithm" but I don't understand what that means. I'm fairly new to coding and have a lot more knowledge to gain.

Can anyone help? I posted pictures from my patch below.

Thanks!

!(IMG_0808.PNG)
!(IMG_0809.PNG)
!(IMG_0810.PNG)
!(IMG_0811.PNG)
!(IMG_0812.PNG)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the app you're trying to **Hack** is server-sided. [Flex 3](http://cydia.saurik.com/package/com.johncoates.flex3/) isn't that useful anymore when it comes to hacking iOS applications unless you're trying to modify a basic offline non server-sided game.

**To be a bit more clear**, when you're trying to modify how much "Bubbles" you receive in **Highrise** with Flex 3, it doesn't work because those "Bubbles" are stored on a server. When they're being used, the game will fetch them from the server.

> The only problem now is that it gives the user the amount but it disappears

That's because Flex 3 only changes the **Visual** number of the "Bubbles" and not the actual server-sided stored amount.

> I received one suggestion so far which was to try "Reversing the subtract algorithm" but I don't understand what that means.

This is a bit of a more **Advanced way** to hack an application. You basically load the application's binary in a disassembler program like [IDA Pro](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/) find the algorithm that subtracts the "Bubbles". This is a very long subject to understand to I suggest you go on this website https://www.iosgods.com and learn how to hack games using a disassembler + debugger. They have nice [tutorials](https://iosgods.com/topic/852-tutorial-how-to-hack-using-ida/) on how to get started.